# UITableView Subview when swipe to show "extras"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to implement a "extras" menu for a app I am creating. Essentially I have a UITableView with multiple types of cells, when a user swipes to the left on the cell I want to be able to dynamically show them "extras" they can do. For example on a post they can swipe over and then see options like share, like ...ect. If you have used the Alien Blue app on ios for Reddit then that is what I am looking to do...

So far I have the swipe recognizer working and it identifies the type of cell properly... I just don't know how to start the subview programming...

Do I just make every cell larger and hide the extras until swipe or do I dynamically add views to each cell as I go...

Thank for any advice or help

I can provide code if needed....

A

Comment: Perform the following search on github - the first few hits are for table cells that provide extra options when you swipe on the cell: https://github.com/search?q=uitableviewcell&ref=cmdform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are right, and at least, that's how I did on my cell.

The only difference is i am not making the cell width large than window width. I add a view with the extra stuff, in my case it's a delete button, under the regular cell.contentview. then when the cell detects a swipe from right to left, it will call a function to handle the gesture.

Since i want the user to see that delete button when drag the cell to the left and show that button entirely when they pan the cell far enough

here is a snippet for how i handle the pan gesture,

```
CGPoint _originalTouchPoint;

- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    switch (recognizer.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
            //save the original touch point when pan starts
            _originalTouchPoint = [recognizer locationInView:_tableView];
            break;

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
            [self handlePan:recognizer];
            break;

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
            [self panEnded:recognizer];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    MyCell *ourCell = (MyCell *)recognizer.view;

    CGPoint touchPoint = [recognizer locationInView:_tableView];
    float movedDistance = (_originalTouchPoint.x - touchPoint.x);

    if(movedDistance < 0)
       movedDistance = 0;

    float maxX = ourCell.deleteButton.frame.size.width;

    float ourTranslation = MAX(-1 * ourCell.deleteButton.frame.size.width, -1 * movedDistance);
    ourCell.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(ourTranslation, 0.0f);

    // i only show the button when user pan all the way though
    _shouldDeleteButtonShow = movedDistance / maxX >= 1.0;
}

- (void)panEnded:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    MyCell *ourCell = (MyCell *)recognizer.view;

    if (_shouldDeleteButtonShow)
    {
        //do whatever you want in this case
    }
    else
    {
       //move the cell back to normal
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                         animations:^
        {
            ourCell.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        }];
    }

}
```

Those are my codes, maybe not working exactly like you want, but hopefully, that gave you a rough idea about how to do this

Comment: Thanks for your help - I figured out a way to do it by incorporating what you said : accepting