# UITableView - Multiple edit styles

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

In the Apple Mail app you can swipe to either Modify or Trash an email, like so:

[image]

Is it possible to do this with out-of-box functions from UIKit? I can only seem to get one type of control (Delete) to appear. Did Apple create a custom style for the mail app?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a very "Out-of-Box" function like that, maybe you can check this library:

SWTableViewCell: https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell

here is a quick preview for the library: [image]

If you really wish to dig into it and find out how to do the swipe to see extras, i have an answer in this post.

[UITableView Subview when swipe to show "extras"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343568/uitableview-subview-when-swipe-to-show-extras/21344579#21344579)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an you of the box codes but here is a link to a project in github that does exactly what you want.

https://github.com/TeehanLax/UITableViewCell-Swipe-for-Options

You have to modify your cell though something along the following.

```
enter c UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds))];
FscrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) + kCatchWidth, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds));
scrollView.delegate = self;
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;

[self.contentView addSubview:scrollView];
self.scrollView = scrollView;

UIView *scrollViewButtonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) - kCatchWidth, 0, kCatchWidth, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds))];
self.scrollViewButtonView = scrollViewButtonView;
[self.scrollView addSubview:scrollViewButtonView];

// Set up our two buttons
UIButton *moreButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
moreButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.78f green:0.78f blue:0.8f alpha:1.0f];
moreButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, kCatchWidth / 3.0f, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds));
[moreButton setTitle:@"More" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[moreButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[moreButton addTarget:self action:@selector(userPressedMoreButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.scrollViewButtonView addSubview:moreButton];

UIButton *shareButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
shareButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1.0f];
shareButton.frame = CGRectMake(kCatchWidth / 3.0f, 0, kCatchWidth / 3.0f, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds));
[shareButton setTitle:@"Share" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[shareButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[shareButton addTarget:self action:@selector(userPressedMoreButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.scrollViewButtonView addSubview:shareButton];

UIButton *deleteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
deleteButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.231f blue:0.188f alpha:1.0f];
deleteButton.frame = CGRectMake(kCatchWidth / 3.0f+kCatchWidth / 3.0f, 0, kCatchWidth / 3.0f, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds));
[deleteButton setTitle:@"Delete" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[deleteButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(userPressedDeleteButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.scrollViewButtonView addSubview:deleteButton];

UIView *scrollViewContentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds))];
scrollViewContentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.scrollView addSubview:scrollViewContentView];
self.scrollViewContentView = scrollViewContentView;

UILabel *scrollViewLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(self.scrollViewContentView.bounds, 10, 0)];
self.scrollViewLabel = scrollViewLabel;
[self.scrollViewContentView addSubview:scrollViewLabel];
```

I hope this helps you.